# Relations between convergence on boundary of power series, and the uniformity of convergence

Tags: calculus, convergence-divergence, power-series, uniform-convergence

Given a power series $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n x^n \ ,x \in \mathbb R\ $ with radius of convergence $R$.

Is that true that:

- If the series does not converge at one boundary, $R$ or $-R$, then the convergence on $(R,-R)$ is not uniform.
- If the series converge at $R$ (or $-R$), then the convergence is uniform on $[0,R]$ (or $[-R,0]$). (not just from $0$, from any $r<R$.)

Comment: The first statement is true, and more or less trivial: If a sequence of functions continuous on $[-R,R]$ converges uniformly on $(-R,R)$ then it's immediate that it actually converges uniformly on $[-R,R]$. The second is also true, but it's not quite so trivial; it follows by "summation by parts", as in the proof of Abel's Theorem. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel%27s_theorem

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Would you please elaborate?

Comment: Seem better if you think about it some more first, and also look at the proof of Abel's Theorem and think about how that might apply.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich I mean about the first one, you said it's immediate and trivial, but I don't see it =\

Comment: The fact that it's immediate and trivial is why I say you should think about it some more. Start with the definition of uniform convergence...

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich something to do with $\sup_{x \in (-R,R)} \lvert f_n(x) - f(x)\rvert = \sup_{x\in [-R,R]} \lvert f_n(x) - f(x)\rvert$ ? Why is that equality true?

Comment: Yes, it has a lot to do with that. Better to consider $\sup|f_n-f_m|$. The sup over this set equals the sup over that set because $|f_n-f_m|$ is continuous on $[-R,R]$.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich and what exactly do I need for the second one? the proof for Abel is for complex numbers and I am not quite familiar with those...

Comment: Ignore the complex numbers on that page - pretend everything is happening on the interval $[-1,1]$.